# how to speedup tensorflow RNN inference time

Tags: python, tensorflow, inference

We've trained a tf-seq2seq model for question answering. The main framework is from [google/seq2seq](https://github.com/google/seq2seq). We use bidirectional RNN( GRU encoders/decoders 128units), adding soft attention mechanism.

We limit maximum length to 100 words. It mostly just generates 10~20 words.

For model inference, we try two cases:

1. normal(greedy algorithm). Its inference time is about 40ms~100ms
2. beam search. We try to use beam width 5, and its inference time is about 400ms~1000ms.

So, we want to try to use beam width 3, its time may decrease, but it may also influence the final effect.

So are there any suggestion to decrease inference time for our case? Thanks.

Comment: One of the most limiting factors in RNN forward-propagation is the vocabulary size.

Comment: thanks for your comment. Our target vocabulary size is about 8000.  it can be reduced to 5000 if we set frequency limit.   We may try to use small vocabulary size latter.

Comment: According to what you commmented I would recommend that you disdill the algorithm into a smaller network.

Comment: Thanks.  We can try to decrease network size.

Answer (score 1):

1. you can do [network compression](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1710.09282.pdf).
2. cut the sentence into pieces by [byte-pair-encoding](http://www.aclweb.org/anthology/P16-1162) or [unigram language model](https://arxiv.org/abs/1804.10959) and etc and then try [TreeLSTM](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1503.00075.pdf).
3. you can try faster softmax like adaptive softmax](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1609.04309.pdf)
4. try [cudnnLSTM](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/compat/v1/keras/layers/CuDNNLSTM)
5. try [dilated RNN](https://papers.nips.cc/paper/6613-dilated-recurrent-neural-networks.pdf)
6. switch to CNN like dilated CNN, or BERT for parallelization and more efficient GPU support

Comment: Thank you!  Our application needs output one realtime response for user query.  So we just feed one query sentence into model, and let model output one response.  And our batch_size=1 for inference.

Answer (score 0):

If you require improved performance, I'd propose that you use [OpenVINO](https://docs.openvino.ai/latest/openvino_docs_install_guides_overview.html). It reduces inference time by graph pruning and fusing some operations. Although OpenVINO is optimized for Intel hardware, it should work with any CPU.

[Here](https://docs.openvino.ai/latest/openvino_docs_performance_benchmarks_openvino.html#bert-base-cased-124) are some performance benchmarks for NLP model (BERT) and various CPUs.

It's rather straightforward to convert the Tensorflow model to OpenVINO unless you have fancy custom layers. The full tutorial on how to do it can be found [here](https://github.com/openvinotoolkit/openvino_notebooks/tree/main/notebooks/101-tensorflow-to-openvino). Some snippets below.

**Install OpenVINO**

The easiest way to do it is using PIP. Alternatively, you can use [this tool](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/developer/tools/openvino-toolkit/download.html) to find the best way in your case.

```
pip install openvino-dev[tensorflow2]
```

**Use Model Optimizer to convert SavedModel model**

The Model Optimizer is a command-line tool that comes from OpenVINO Development Package. It converts the Tensorflow model to IR, which is a default format for OpenVINO. You can also try the precision of FP16, which should give you better performance without a significant accuracy drop (just change data_type). Run in the command line:

```
mo --saved_model_dir "model" --input_shape "[1, 3, 224, 224]" --data_type FP32 --output_dir "model_ir"
```

**Run the inference**

The converted model can be loaded by the runtime and compiled for a specific device e.g. CPU or GPU (integrated into your CPU like Intel HD Graphics). If you don't know what is the best choice for you, just use AUTO.

```
# Load the network
ie = Core()
model_ir = ie.read_model(model="model_ir/model.xml")
compiled_model_ir = ie.compile_model(model=model_ir, device_name="CPU")

# Get output layer
output_layer_ir = compiled_model_ir.output(0)

# Run inference on the input image
result = compiled_model_ir([input_image])[output_layer_ir]
```

Disclaimer: I work on OpenVINO.